# GitSharp cannot find cloned bare repository

Tags: git, gitsharp

I have created a bare clone of a Git repository and placed it on a shared network drive. I am trying to open this bare repository from GitSharp.

I used the following command to clone the repository:

> $ git clone --bare my_project my_project.git

With GitSharp I can open the repository on the shared network drive without a problem. However if I attempt to connect to the cloned bare repository (on the same server), GitSharp cannot find the repository. The cloned repository is shared just as the original is.

> var git_url = Repository.FindRepository(p); // where 'p' is the path to the shared bare clone.

The above returns the git url if I connect to the orginal repository but it returns NULL if I attempt to connect to the clone.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of what the path and the url look like?

Comment: The network path both just look like your typical network path: //servername/sharedFolder They are both shared but only the orginal repository (the one I cloned) seems to work with GitSharp. I'm wondering if GitSharp will not work with a bare clone for some reason..